# What is this plant / weed? (with photos)

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this plant?  It's about 6 feet tall now, though I assume most people don't let them grow this big.

This is growing currently (early August) in northwest Ohio.

[image: tall weed]
[image: close-up of weed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In North America this is known as Common Mullein (*Verbascum thapsus*), there are many names for this plant described on the wikipedia page, most notable: "Cowboy toilet paper".

This is a biennial plant, and is an introduced species in North America. It is original from Europe/Asia/North Africa.

Comment: Do not let this go to seed, as it will release thousands of future weeds. Cut the flowering stalks now and dispose of in the garbage, not a compost pile. The rest of the plant will die on its own. These weeds are very difficult to eradicate except by manually digging them up when young; their fuzzy leaves prevent the plant from taking up any herbicides (including RoundUp) sprayed on them.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Did you just know what it was, or do you have some quick way of looking up weeds?

Comment: I have seen this one before growing here in Europe. I found it a nice plant so I then looked up what it was. It is called different in Dutch (king's candle literally translated), so I had to google the English and Latin name for you.

Comment: Small birds eat the seeds all winter here in mountains of Northwest U.SA.